# Should hourly email notification accumulate all the notification from past hours?

Tags: notification, email, experience, settings

I am designing an email notification setting for an ERP.

[image]

Based on the image above:

1. User selected the 'Hourly' option for email notification.
2. In the first hour away from the system, the user gets 3 new notifications and this update is emailed to the user "3 new notifications since your last login {date}{time}".
3. For the 2nd-hour user is away, user gets 1 additional new notification.

Should the system send the second email as '4 new notifications'(total #notifications of all hours away) or '1 new notification'? (only #notification in that hour).

Comment: This is a simple process if you are comfortable with Dynamic Email [(gmail's announcement)](https://www.blog.google/products/gmail/take-action-and-stay-up-to-date-with-dynamic-email-in-gmail/), This is an easy task. Consider an example:

*Take commenting in Google Docs, for example. Instead of receiving individual email notifications when someone mentions you in a comment, now, you’ll see an up-to-date thread in Gmail where you can easily reply or resolve the comment, right from within the message.* (quoted from the above linked article)

Comment: Probably this is obvious but just to be safe: No matter which option you choose, please only use *new* notifications for deciding whether another email should be sent or not. Hourly notifications for the same unread notification would be very annoying

Answer (score 16):

As the user requested hourly updates, they'd probably be confused if notifications from previous updates were included.

Of course, the text has to be modified: 1 new notification since last update.

A proposal for giving full information: 1 new notification since last update, in total 4 notifications unread.

Comment: 'unread' might be a bad choice of words, as you don't know whether the user read the last email (e.g. after you sent the new email). "in total 4 notifications since last login" sounds safer/more correct.

Comment: Of course, the exact wording is up to debate :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could section the email into "New Notification" and "Unread Notification" sections as Gerda suggested. This has a real benefit for users that might be away for multiple hours.

For example, if a user was offline for a full day and they wake up to 24 new emails from you, they could just read that last email sent to see a full day's work of misread notification instead of having to read all 24 emails.

Answer (score 0):

To reply to your title No. Each new email should have only the past hour unread notification, otherwise the user inevitably will scan the read ones every time.

I myself when I read on Gmail the x platform's notification I check if they are read/unread and then their date and time.